Today's solution to the R8168 network card problem
I am using a dell optiplex 3000 thin client with Realtek RTL8111 network chip and am running Ubuntu 24.04 with kernel 6.8.0.45-generic
By default the system boots with R8169 driver enabled which leads after some time to timeout errors:
NETDEV WATCHDOG: enp1s0 (r8169): transmit queue 0 timed out

So i blacklisted the r8169 and tried to install an R8168 driver, either

from the Realtek website version 8.053.0.
or as suggestet here the dkms package version 8.052.01 from https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/r8168-dkms
In both cases I could confirm that the driver was loaded and in use, but after a few seconds, the errors

enp1s0: pci link is down
enp1s0: cmd=0xFF, should be 0x07

appeared. I also tried to power cycle the computer, but to no avail.
I wrote in the title "Today's solution", since it seems like the r8168 drivers fixed the problems a couple of years ago, and I am wondering if this is supposed to be still the case and what could be wrong on my side?
